# Running an Ansible ping on a remote host fails

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, automation

I've just getting started to study Ansible and how it can improves my job. With that said, I'm facing issues when I try to ping a host with Ansible (`ansible all -m ping -vv`). Ansible is installed on host A and host B is configured on /etc/ansible/hosts. Both hosts run Ubuntu 16.04.03 LTS and I can SSH from A to B without password.

Ansible ping returns

```
172.28.25.81 | FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "failed": true, 
    "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 172.28.25.81 closed.\r\n", 
    "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
    "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
    "rc": 0
}
```

My software versions are:

- Ansible 2.4.1.0
- Python 2.7.12

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you started using Ansible, I believe you read what [`ping` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ping_module.html) is for (reading just the header is enough in this case):

> ping - Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success

Ansible tells you:

> /bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found

So it likely could not "**verify a usable python**".

---

And there is a reason for that: Ubuntu 16.04 does not come with Python 2 installed, so Ansible fails to run `/usr/bin/python` executable.

You need to:

- install Python 2 on the target machine, or
- instruct Ansible to use Python 3 (it's working, but is not yet officially supported) - there is a [`ansible_python_interpreter`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_inventory.html#list-of-behavioral-inventory-parameters) setting for that.